# github network shows a mysterious branch

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

I work on 2 main branches namely 'develop' and 'master'.

Everything was working perfectly fine until today.

When I saw the network graph on github, there was a mysterious **yellow colored branch** coming out of master and **having no name**.

I have attached the images both labelled and unlabeled version of network graph.

```
What could have possibly gone wrong?
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is it an open source project? But it's obvious that someone created a branch, then merged other branches into it and finally merged it back into master

Comment: Nope. It is not an open source project.

Comment: No I checked the history. If that was the case, it should have got some name. Every branch there has a name but the yellow branch.

Comment: "it should have got some name" -- it shouldn't. You are free to drop the branch after you're done. In git branches are just named pointers which don't change the history itself in any way, so "dropping a branch" literally means deleting a particular reference to a particular changeset.

Comment: To drop the branch, I should know the name of the branch. When I list the branches, there is no branch having a blank name.

Comment: why do you think there was no name? "When I list the branches, there is no branch having a blank name" -- of course you don't see it - it was dropped one day. Again - branch in git is just a pointer. That's it. You can make a reference to **any** changeset and name it by any branch name you want at any time you want.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41385/discussion-between-abhijit-and-zerkms)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At some point did you merge a branch with `git merge mybranch --no-ff` and then delete `mybranch`? The `--no-ff` (no fast forward) forces git to make a merge commit so there's a record of the branch existing at some point, however the name is now gone.

Comment: In that particular case fast forward wasn't even possible, since the last commit before merge didn't belong to `master`

Comment: Is it possible that it is clone of master? May be to keep the network tidy? Does it happen?

Comment: @aBhijit: I have already explained how it happened: someone created a branch, merged another branches into it, merged back into `master` and dropped it. What particularly don't you like in this explanation?

Comment: Yes @zerkms - I had a discussion with my developers, that seems to have happened. He accidentally once pulled a branch from master instead of develop and then deleted it after the merge. Thanks a lot for pointing out the possibility.